# jquery highlight effect

Tags: jquery, highlight, effect

i'm trying to figure out the code for the jquery selector test found at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/trysel.asp?filename=trysel_basic&jqsel=p.intro,%23choose.

I'm getting error:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "h1" jquery.js:4241

in Chrome developer tool when i enter h1 in the text box. By right it should highlight "Welcome to My Homepage" which is within `<h1>` tag.

Can someone point out on where i'm going wrong? Thank you.

The following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
        var hl_str= '"'+$(":text").val()+'"';
        //document.write(hl_str);
        $(hl_str).effect("highlight",{color:"ff0000"},3000);
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
<input type="button" value="Edit and Click Me">
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<p class="intro">My name is Donald</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey</p>
Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
<li>Goofy</li>
<li>Mickey</li>
<li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Jqeury UI library for `effect()` ?

Comment: Check if you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/NaM3N/

Comment: I don't have jquery UI library. I only have jquery.js. From where can I download jquery UI for free? Yes Joy, what i want is exactly like in jsfiddle website.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded jquery UI library from

    http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/03/jquery-ui-1-9-milestone-7-accordion/

Then I modified the code referring to the jsfiddle link that joy at given above.

Now it works fine. Thank you Ahsan Rathod and Joy! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the quotes when building the "hl_str" string.

Try:

```
var hl_str = $(":text").val();
```

Comment: He is not using Jquery UI Library.

Comment: The bug in question is caused by having a string with double quotes in it.

Comment: no, i don't have jquery UI library. From where can I download that for free?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just not matching some objects.
I suggest you try using the contains to search for the value instead

```
jQuery('p:contains("Donald")').effect("highlight",{color:"#ff0000"},3000);
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

`effect()` isn't a function of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts not perfect but i think is a possible way to do:

JS:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
        var hl_str = $("input[type=text]").val();   

    $('#mycontainer').find('*').contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 3) {
            var txt = $(this).text().replace(hl_str, '<span class="effect">'+hl_str+'</span>');
            $(this).parent().html(txt);
        }
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.effect{ color: #ff0000; }
```

Not work, like you see at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svvhA/), but is a initial point ;-)